# How to SQL group by based on common membership

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have a table like the following, which just say what person is matches someone else on the same team (including yourself):

```
person1|person2
-------------
A      | A
B      | A
C      | A
A      | B
B      | B
C      | B
A      | C
B      | C
C      | C
X      | X
Y      | X
X      | Y
Y      | Y
```

I would like to have two records using a GROUP_CONCAT and have the following

```
team
-------
A, B, C
X, Y
```

The order of the GROUP_CONCAT is not too important but I don't want repeats like "A, B, C", "B, A, C". Or better yet would settle for just any sort of teamid along with the member:

```
teamid|person
-------------
1     | A
1     | B
1     | C
2     | X
2     | Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data, you can handle this by doing:

```
select distinct group_concat(person2 order by person2)
from t
group by person1;
```

As a note:  you can swap `person2` and `person1` and get the same results.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I think the "order by" cause isn't necessary since it work fine without it. (SQLite doesn't support it)

Comment: @swdev In this particular case, it works, but only because the rows happen to be read in the correct order. ORDER BY is still required.

Comment: @CL . . . The question was not tagged SQLite when I answered it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [group_concat()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) to generate the list of team members.
To ensure that `group_concat()` creates only one unique result for each possible set of team members, sort the data first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_concat(person2)
FROM (SELECT person1, person2
      FROM MyTable
      ORDER BY person1, person2)
GROUP BY person1;
```